# Create Custom TestNG Report - WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, report, webdriver, testng

I'm trying to implement org.testng IReporter Interface. My Java is not that great, base on some example I found online I was able to create a Reporter class. The problem I'm having is how to use it and where do I call it and how and which parameters to pass to it?

public class Reporter implements IReporter {

```
public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory){
      ISuiteResult results =suites.get(0).getResults().get("Sanity Suite");
      ITestContext context = results.getTestContext();

      IResultMap passedTests = context.getPassedTests();
      IResultMap failedTests = context.getFailedTests();

      // Print all test exceptions...
      for( ITestResult r: failedTests.getAllResults()) {
          System.out.println( r.getThrowable());
      }
}
```

}

For example I have this WebDriver Selenium TestNG test:

public class VerifyTest extends TestBase {

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    verifyTrue(false);
    verifyEquals("pass", "fail");
    verifyFalse(true);
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    verifyTrue(false);
    assertEquals("pass", "fail");
    verifyFalse(true);
}
```

How would I use my Reporter to get a customize report at the end of the run???

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Just expand your skeleton above to generate your results where you want them, .xml, .html, text file, etc...

Comment: Thank you Cedric, can you be a little more specific though? How do I make connection between Reporter and my Test?

Comment: The parameters passed to your generateReport() method contain the entire result of the test suite, so everything is there. If you're confused, take a look at the existing reporters (look at all the classes that implement IReporter) and see how they retrieve their results.

Answer (score 1):

David, you can add your custom reporter to your testng.xml in case you are invoking your tests through an xml in the suite section.

```
<listeners>
<listener class-name="yourpackage.Reporter"/> </listeners>
```

In case you are programmatically invoking those, then you need to add it through your code as documented @ [Running TestNG programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically)

If you are invoking your tests from command line, refer [this](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-listeners)

This reporter would be invoked by TestNG at then end of all the runs, if you specify in either of the above ways.

Comment: Thank You, it's very helpful, but I'm not getting what I need even after I made this work. What I'm trying to accomplish is to pass parameters based on my code to the reporter, so it would say in the report what I need. For example I have simple test case that check links on the homepage, if one link fails then test is stopped, if I change the code and it runs trough, I get PASS at the end. Any suggestions?

Comment: The results of all testcases are passed by TestNG when it calls the generateReport method of your listener.  So your results variable contains all the pass-fail information of your suite.  If you would like to set custom data on failure, then you would need to explicitly set it to the TestResult object in your afterInvocation methods by using setAttribute function.

Comment: When you say you change your code, are you changing assert to verify?  Asserts stop execution where they fail, whereas verify is a soft assert, as in, it doesn't halt execution, but it would still mark the case as pass.  You may want to have a look at : http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/guide/using-soft-assertions-in-testng/  to get an idea of a way to handle these..

Answer (score 1):

I [created a project that is an example of generating a customized report](https://github.com/djangofan/selenium-framework-concept2).

The basic idea is to create a Listener class and reference it in the testing.xml file.

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="qa.hs.framework.CustomReportListener"/>
  </listeners>
```

And then create the class:

```
 public class CustomReportListener implements IReporter {

    @Override
    public void generateReport( List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, 
           String outputDirectory ) {
       System.out.println();
       //Iterating over each suite included in the test
       for (ISuite suite : suites) {
       //Following code gets the suite name
       String suiteName = suite.getName();
       //Getting the results for the said suite
       Map<String, ISuiteResult> suiteResults = suite.getResults();
       for ( ISuiteResult sr : suiteResults.values() ) {
          ITestContext tc = sr.getTestContext();
          System.out.println("Passed tests for suite '" + suiteName + "' is:" +
               tc.getPassedTests().getAllResults().size());
        }
        CustomReport cr = new CustomReport();
        cr.generateReport( xmlSuites, suites, outputDirectory );
        ...
```

Then, from that Listener class you can create a "Report Writer" class that creates any arbitrary HTML output using something like so:

```
public class CustomReport extends CustomReportListener
{
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger( CustomReport.class );
        private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" MMM d 'at' hh:mm a");

        private String reportFileName = Constants.reportFileName;
        private PrintWriter m_out;
        private int m_row;
        private Integer m_testIndex;
        private int m_methodIndex;
        private Scanner scanner;

        @Override
        public void generateReport( List<XmlSuite> xml, List<ISuite> suites, String outdir ) {
                try {
                        m_out = createWriter( outdir );
                }
                catch ( IOException e ) {
                        LOG.error("output file", e);
                        return;
                }
                startHtml(m_out);
                generateSuiteSummaryReport(suites);
                generateMethodSummaryReport(suites);
                generateMethodDetailReport(suites);
                endHtml(m_out);
                m_out.flush();
                m_out.close();
        }
```

And finally, from that "CustomReport" class your "generate report" methods all have access to all data from the report, such as:

```
testContext.getPassedTests()
Map<String, ISuiteResult> r = suite.getResults()
method.getDescription()
method.getTestClass().getName()
ITestResult.SUCCESS
tests.getAllMethods()
overview.getStartDate().getTime()
overview.getIncludedGroups()
etc.
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I found what I needed from the git project. All I wanted to know was how to get the info about the time each method took to run.

Comment: The info about how much time each method takes to run is already on the default report.  See the screenshot here:  https://github.com/djangofan/testng-custom-report-example

Comment: Hey @djangofan sorry for bringing this back from the dead. Can you use the above to generate the report as the tests are progressing instead of the report being generated at the end of the tests? I'm looking to do something similar as above except I want to generate a HTML Monitoring Report, where you can view the report to monitor the tests progress. Thanks.

Comment: @colin - Then I think you want to use something called `Extent Reports` .

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@Listeners(ReporterClassName.class)
```

ex:
@Listeners(Reporter.class)

public class VerifyTest extends TestBase

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful reporting with realtime report of any running test is possible using RealTime report plugin. Very easy to use and no modification needed in existing code, for details please visit this github url [RealTimeReport](https://github.com/startingwithseleniumwebdriver/RealTimeReport)

You can find details implementation of different TestNg Reporting intrfaces

[image]